# dynamic child control with dynamic properties and bubble event in flex 4.5

Tags: apache-flex

hi i have a question while reading Flex 4 Cookbook i came across the method to dynamically adding control to the container controls but nowhere i came across with how to provide them with the dynamic properties and events like they have created a button dynamically inside a group control but what good a button be if i cannot give it an event dynamically. in the same way i want to add a tree view inside a vbox but what good that be if cannot provide a data provider to it dynamically.actually i am creating an web application where i add the tree view to a vbox and i want to the data provider should also be dynamic depending upon the option i have selected in the combo box.

Comment: Events and dataproviders may be assigned dynamically - could you cite the Flex 4 Cookbook example or be more specific about the implementation you are attempting to achieve?

Comment: sir the book is "Flex 4 Cookbook: Real-world Recipes for Developing Rich Internet Applications"
 and on page 28 their is the example of How to Dynamically add and remove children. and the example goes like this  "<s:Button label='add' click='{mycontainer.addElement( new Button());}' "/>     <s:Group id='mycontainer'>         <s:layout> <s:VerticalLayout/><s:layout></s:Group>

Answer (score 0):

you can use the mediator pattern. For example you catch events from combobox(which includes changed data) to the parent container, just make sure the bubbling = true during the dispatchEvent call. In this case your components are decoupled and this good for the application maintaining in future.

Comment: sir could you be more elaborate on this or could you let me know the link i can follow

Comment: sir this example could be found here http://www.rprustagi.com/netzoom/NetZoomDCMain.html